# Reference a custom field in NS on the standard HTML transaction form/SO email form

Tags: html, netsuite

Does anyone know how to reference a NS field in the standard HTML form?

I have a custom field on my SO that links to our external website. The field uses a formula to pull the NS SO internal ID to create the link so we can send it out to the customer. That field works perfect and I was able to get that link to display properly as an element on the standard PDF form layout that gets emailed to the customer as an attachment on the SO notification email.

Now, here is the issue, I don't know how to reference it on the "a href" html tag in the HTML code on the transaction HTML layout. I know the field name/backend ID, I just don't know how to reference it in the "a href" html tag, this is what I have so far:

```
<a href="{custbodypg_link_so}">Securely View, Edit, & Track the status of this order</a>
```

(in the curly brackets is my field name and I removed the carrots so the exact code would show up in this text box)

Does anyone know how to get that field from the SO form to show up in the Transaction HTML Layout form?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out. I needed to have the `href` set as `<NLCUSTBODYPG_LINK_SO>`.